# Cannot get local JSON file data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I tried a lot to get data from the json file that is in inside the reactjs project folder
I even tried getting json data of package.json file that is inside the reactjs folder but still got error
How can I locate/get data from local JSON file
I kept getting only error as output

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/flat-trade/package.json")
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response + "hello");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log("error");
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is local file, you can directly import into react file

```
import * as data from './flat-trade/package.json';
```

Comment: I tried it too but it said " Cannot convert object to primitive value" and I also did not get the data of the json :(